# Undeclared Identifier for Windows Form

Tags: visual-c++

Trying open second form upon button press leads to crash.
I have closely followed many tutorials, successfully replicating them to no avail.

All relevant files have been #included (including stfAfx.h), and the name of the form I am trying to open has almost certainly been declared.

```cpp
//Upon button click:
    this->Hide();
    SavedListsScreen^ sls = gcnew SavedListsScreen();
    sls->ShowDialog();
```

The second form is intended to open, but instead the error messages
`'SavedListsScreen': undeclared identifier` and
`'sls': undeclared identifier`
are returned.

Comment: That doesn't look much like a crash.  A compiler error like this is common when you have a circular dependency between .h files.